# Matrix whose rank differs depending on the domain of the elements

Tags: matrices, finite-fields, matrix-rank

I am looking for a matrix in $\mathbb{F}_2$ which changes its rank if interpreted as a matrix of a different field.

Formally: I am looking for a pair of matrices $A \in \mathbb{F}_2^{m \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{F}_p^{m \times n}$ for some $p > 2$, such that

- $B_{ij} = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } A_{ij} = 1 \\ 0 & \text{else}\end{cases}$
- $\text{rank}(A) \neq \text{rank}(B)$

Do matrices like that exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure: choose any matrix of zeros and ones whose determinant is non-zero and even. It will be invertible over $F_p$ for any prime not dividing its determinant, but not over $F_2$.

Here's a random example:
$$\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)$$

Comment: Note that this requires $m=n\geq4$.

Comment: @Servaes I suppose what it really requires is that our matrix contains a four by four submatrix (i.e. m and n are both at least four, but can be distinct).

Comment: Indeed this is what the question requires. You mention the determinant in your answer, which is why I noted you must have $m=n$.

Comment: @Servaes Yes, but you get an example for arbitrary (possibly distinct) m and n by just completing this matrix to an m by n matrix by adding a bunch of zeros. The result will have rank four modulo any prime p not dividing the determinant of the minor, but smaller rank modulo 2.

Comment: @Servaes By the way, it's not totally clear to me whether the OP wanted one example for some particular m and n, or, for each pair of positive integers, wanted to know whether it was possible for that pair. Obviously I lean towards the former interpretation.

Comment: I agree entirely, and I also lean towards the former interpretation. But I thought it was worth mentioning that it's impossible for small enough $m$ and $n$.

Comment: I was just looking for one example matrix for one arbitrary pair of n,m. Thanks!